# What is the equation for viscous heating?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, viscosity-solutions

I have been reading a [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/braginskii-magnetohydrodynamics-for-arbitrary-magnetic-topologies-coronal-applications/B223D074539703D217B072378A369FD8) which talks about viscosity in a plasma. They say that the viscous force is given by the divergence of the viscous stress tensor, $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}$. Therefore, the viscous heating rate must be given the dot product of the velocity with this force, $-\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}$. They say that the heating rate is given by $\boldsymbol{\sigma}:\boldsymbol{\nabla v}.$ Therefore, the following must be true
$$\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}=-\boldsymbol{\sigma}:\boldsymbol{\nabla v},$$
however, they do not prove this result. Do you know how we can prove this result? Under what conditions does this equation hold?

Comment: I don't think the two sides are mathematically identical. There must be some physics going on here. Is the divergence of $\sigma\cdot v$ zero?

Comment: I'm not sure. In the small magnetic field limit, the viscous stress tensor can be approximated with $$\boldsymbol{\sigma}=\boldsymbol{\nabla v}+(\boldsymbol{\nabla v})^T-\frac{2}{3}(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{v})\boldsymbol{I}$$ (with the viscosity coefficent equal to 1).